# how to find independent path?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I confused while find independent path.

What should be $\lambda$ for the path independent of Moreover evaluate the integral for this value of $\lambda.$

$$\int_{(2,4)}^{(1.2)} (\frac{xy+\lambda}{y})dx+(\frac{2y\lambda-x}{y^2})dy$$

**Exactly Differential and
it could be check out conservative whether.**

$$\int_{(2,4)}^{(1.2)} x+(\frac{\lambda}{y})dx+(\frac{2\lambda}{y}-\frac{x}{y^2})dy$$
$$ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=\frac{-\lambda}{y^2}=\frac{-1}{y^2}=\lambda=1 $$
$$\int_{(2,4)}^{(1.2)} (x+(\frac{1}{y}))dx+(\frac{2}{y}-\frac{x}{y^2}))dy$$
$$\int_{(2,4)}^{(1.2)} x+(\frac{1}{y})dx =\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{y}+y(u) $$
$$\int_{(2,4)}^{(1.2)} (\frac{2}{y}-(\frac{x}{y^2})dy =\frac{x}{y}+2ln+x(v)) $$

**We need potantial function.**

$$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x^2}{2}+2ln(y)\Biggr|_{(1,2)}^{(2,4)}$$
$$ \frac{2}{4}+\frac{4}{2}+2ln(4)-\Biggr[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+2ln(2)\Biggr]$$
$$\bf 1.5+2ln(2)\approx 2,8862$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you flipped the points in the final calculation, your result should have a negative sign.

The calculation of $\lambda$ is correct.

But it is not necessary to calculate the potential. Since you now know that the integral is path-independent, you may just choose a path along which you can integrate easily.

A "nice" path - after flipping the endpoints - parallel to the axes could be
$$C_1: (1+t,2), t \in [0,1] \text{ and } C_2: (2,2+t), t\in [0,2]$$

So, you get

$$\int_{(2,4)}^{(1,2)} \left(x+ \frac{1}{y}\right)dx+\left(\frac{2}{y} - \frac{x}{y^2}\right)dy = \color{blue}{-}\int_{\color{blue}{(1,2)}}^{\color{blue}{(2,4)}} \left(x+ \frac{1}{y}\right)dx+\left(\frac{2}{y} - \frac{x}{y^2}\right)dy$$
$$= -\left[\int_0^1\left(1+t + \frac 12\right)dt + \int_0^2\left(\frac 2{2+t} -\frac 2{(2+t)^2}\right)dt\right] = -\left(\frac 32 + 2\ln 2\right)$$

Comment: Thank you Sir.You are right.I had do mixed bounds. So,is it true my solution method ?

Comment: Your way is correct but might not work if the function is too complicated to integrate easily as the present one. When you calculate the potential you have two typos: After integrating with respect to $x$ you get $u(y)$ and not $y(u)$. Similarly, after integrating wrt. $y$ you get $v(x)$ instead of $x(v)$.

Comment: Thanks so much,I am appreciative  to your contributions.

Comment: You are welcome. :-)